# Bottom Navigation view is not expanding in full space

Tags: android, material-design, bottomnavigationview

I want to achieve something like this :

[image]

But when I am using this Bottom Navigation I am getting this, not able to replicate.

Both spacing and elevation are missing.

This is my Navigation view

```
 <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            android:background="@color/dark"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
            app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:itemBackground="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Just remove paddingleft and paddingRight

Comment: No change, it's still the same

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the padding you specified in the Bottom Navigation Bar. Padding is used to specify the space/gap inside the container between its border and inside content. The padding attribute specified in the Navigation Bar may be pushing the menu items towards the center of the navigation bar. Removing the padding attribute should do the trick of evenly spacing the menu items across the navigation bar.